# findOneAndUpdate mongodb push onto existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, push

I have a 2d array of data and I want to push other arrays as single elements onto this array. The user will not have the entire array of arrays and will only put a new one in the database.

This is what I have so far but I need to know how to push the new array into my 2d array in the database:

```
.put((req, res)=>{
    mySchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        id:req.params.id
    },
    req.body,
    (err, updatedrate)=>{
        if(err)return res.status(500).send(err)
        return res.status(201).send(updatedrate)
    })
})
```

Comment: you should provide a sample json object to support your question

Answer (score 6):

try **$addToSet**

```
{ _id: 1, letters: ["a", "b"] }

db.test.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: {letters: [ "c", "d" ] } }
)

{ _id: 1, letters: [ "a", "b", [ "c", "d" ] ] }
```

refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Answer (score 0):

```
const db= new Schema({ 
    arrayName: [],
}); 

db.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { $push: { arrayName: itemAdd } }
```

add itemAdd to arrayName